# unable to open project structure and module settings

Tags: java, android-studio

My error starts when I plug in my mobile phone into my laptop to run my app and everything was fine. But I run the app before my phone was plugged in. So the app run on the simulator and the Gradle started syncing. So I stopped it and rerun it on my phone   I'm using windows 10

So the Gradle sync all day and the run button is disabled and says (Apply changes and restart activity [disabled unexpected exception])

And I can't open File>project structure or module settings (F4).

And I got this in logcat (Run configuration app is not supported in the current project. Cannot obtain the application ID)

I restart the project and Invalidate caches and sync project with Gradle files but nothing helps

And I got a message that says (IDE error occurred) and it shows this [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSuTy.png)

and this is what is written on that page

```
`java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Elhoseny\moaz coffee\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file\debug\..\..\apk\debug\output-metadata.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:885)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:814)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:751)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:441)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:825)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:440)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:794)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:492)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Elhoseny\moaz coffee\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file\debug\..\..\apk\debug\output-metadata.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Elhoseny\moaz coffee\app\build\intermediates\apk_ide_redirect_file\debug\..\..\apk\debug\output-metadata.json (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:219)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157)
    at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:75)
    at com.android.ide.common.build.GenericBuiltArtifactsLoader.loadFromFile(GenericBuiltArtifactsLoader.kt:76)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.util.GradleBuildOutputUtil.loadBuildOutputListingFile(GradleBuildOutputUtil.kt:131)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.GradleAndroidModel.getGenericBuiltArtifactsUsingCache(GradleAndroidModel.java:699)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.GradleAndroidModel.getGenericBuiltArtifactsWithTimestamp(GradleAndroidModel.java:677)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.GradleAndroidModel.getApplicationIdUsingCache(GradleAndroidModel.java:658)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.GradleAndroidModel.getApplicationIdUsingCache(GradleAndroidModel.java:650)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.model.GradleAndroidModel.getApplicationId(GradleAndroidModel.java:303)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.UsageTrackerUtils.getApplicationId(extensions.kt:82)
    at com.android.tools.idea.stats.UsageTrackerUtils.withProjectId(extensions.kt:61)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.logUsageOpen(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:481)
    at com.android.tools.idea.structure.dialog.ProjectStructureConfigurable.showPlace(ProjectStructureConfigurable.kt:261)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectSettingsServiceImpl.showNewPsd(AndroidProjectSettingsServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.structure.AndroidProjectSettingsServiceImpl.openModuleSettings(AndroidProjectSettingsServiceImpl.java:110)
    at com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.AbstractModuleNode.navigate(AbstractModuleNode.java:96)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:83)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:58)
    at com.intellij.util.OpenSourceUtil.navigate(OpenSourceUtil.java:51)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.BaseNavigateToSourceAction.actionPerformed(BaseNavigateToSourceAction.java:24)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.lambda$performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks$4(ActionUtil.java:240)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:261)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:240)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.lambda$performAction$0(ActionMenuItem.java:277)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:236)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:67)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.performAction(ActionMenuItem.java:269)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:284)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.lambda$fireActionPerformed$2(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:111)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:515)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:545)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6652)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6417)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5027)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2784)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4859)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
`   ... 22 more
```

Comment: Since it's a `PrivilegedActionException`, maybe file permissions are in the way? Could be that you are allowed to access those files but the application is not.

Comment: so how can I fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved the error by build> clean project..... build> rebuild project